# Azure - azurerm_email_communication_service

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to deploy an [azurerm_email_communication_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/email_communication_service) using the following terraform code.

```
   terraform{
    required_providers {
      azurerm = {
        source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "3.61.0"
      }
    }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "azurerm_group" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.region
}

resource "azurerm_email_communication_service" "smtp-service" {
  name                = var.service_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.azurerm_group.name
  data_location       = var.data_location
}
```

Everything is good so far but I need a way of obtaining the principal account or any other method to authenticate my app when using this service.

Is there a way of obtaining any authentication data besides principal account?
How can I attach principal account to this resource in terraform and then export the secret data so I can use it to authenticate my application later on? Can someone please, assist me with such information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up single sign-on (SSO) between Azure AD and Terraform Cloud to have your users automatically signed in using their Azure AD accounts.

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/saas-apps/terraform-cloud-tutorial.md#configure-terraform-cloud-sso) for authenticating with SSO.

Goto Azure AD >> Enterprise applications >> Search for terraform cloud and assign a user to it as shown.

[image]

Once it is done, you can set up single sign on under the terraform cloud application.

[image]

Follow the above given document for the clear steps on how to authenticate and integrate it.

Once you have configured the above, you can use [`azurerm_email_communication_service`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/email_communication_service) for an email communication that uses Active Directory for authentication.

I created a user assigned identity and given the necessary privileges for the newly created user under Access control(IAM).

[image]

Below is the modified code as per your requirement.

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "caro"
}
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  name                = "newuser"
  resource_group_name = "caro"
}
resource "azurerm_email_communication_service" "example" {
  name                = "examplemail"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  data_location       = "United States"
  depends_on  = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example]
}
```

Executed `terraform plan` successfully:

[image]

Comment: Did you set up SSO and checked in the above mentioned way? @Anaconda1337